# Apply same set of jQuery methods and code onto multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code it works great but only first function.
I know this js code is very old but I use this for study.

Sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/ieaccunt/gnfutye2/16/

This is live search function and it works fine but ONLY on first input field. 
I have just copied same function and tried to connect 2nd input field. but it doesn't work. I would like to apply same code 5 more times on other elements each.

I wrote 2nd input field like this

I have prepared independent JSON and JS file. I do know its really bad and not smart, but for now I would like to use this .

Here is my html sample

```
<div>
<div class="btn-group">
<input type="text" name="search2" id="search2" placeholder="input 2" class="form-control" size="3000" onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13" />
<span class="searchclear glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
</div>
<ul class="list-group" id="result2"></ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Could someone teach me why After 1st funtion doesn't work. I tried each input filed as independent id and variable...

Comment: first, you need to have unique ID attributes for each elements. In sample you provided, they are repeating, although I see it in sample here that you named them with number suffix

Comment: creating class and object instances of that class would be a good start point

Comment: Dear @niklaz  Thank you for comment. I thoguht I changed ID attributes ... Even I wrote same unique ID at  2nd input . it doesn't work. so I've wondering its not ID problem? I would be very glad if you teach me code.

Comment: @kagemaru, take a look at my answer, it solves the problem of repeating methods onto multiple elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jQuery.fn.extend()` to extend the jQuery with custom methods, that you would apply then to parent element, and children within that element.

see: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/ for more details

This is just a sample and direction how to adjust your code, but incomplete, due to incomplete sample in your question. 
Also, keep in mind to have only unique ID html attributes, but use css classes if you need to repeat elements.

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
    searchAndDisplay: function () {

        return this.each(function () {
            var searchWrapper = $(this);
            $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
            searchWrapper.find('.search').keyup(function () {
         
                searchWrapper.find('.result').html('');
                //  searchWrapper.find('.state').val(''); //not sure what is this, since it is not provided in sample
                var searchField = searchWrapper.find('.search').val();
                var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
                $.getJSON('js/data.json', function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        if (value.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.location.search(expression) != -1) {

                            searchWrapper.find('.result').append(
                                '<li class="list-group-item link-class"' +
                                ' data-name="' + value.name + '"' +
                                ' data-code="' + value.code + '"' +
                                ' data-location="' + value.location + '"' +
                                ' data-image="' + value.image + '"' +
                                '>' + value.name + '</li>');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

            searchWrapper.find('.result').on('click', 'li', function () {
                var name = $(this).data('name');
                var code = $(this).data('code');
                var location = $(this).data('location');


                var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
                searchWrapper.find('.search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));

                searchWrapper.find('.search').attr('readonly', true);


                $(".result").html('');


                searchWrapper.find('.result').after('<input type="hidden" name="name" value="' + name + '">');
                searchWrapper.find('.result').after('<input type="hidden" name="code" value="' + code + '">');
                searchWrapper.find('.result').after('<input type="hidden" name="location" value="' + location + '">');


            });

        });
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
   //then apply same method on each element
    $("#searchComponent-1").searchAndDisplay(); 
    $("#searchComponent-2").searchAndDisplay();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="searchComponent-1">

    <div class="btn-group">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="input 1" class="search form-control" size="3000"
               onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13"/>
        <span class="searchclear glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
    </div>

    <ul class="list-group result"></ul>
</div>

<div id="searchComponent-2">

    <div class="btn-group">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="input 2" class="search form-control" size="3000"
               onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13"/>
        <span class="searchclear glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
    </div>

    <ul class="list-group result"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear @niklaz Thank you for helped me back then. Do me a favor I need your help. Your code is really amazing. I'm beginer of js. I couldn't get <div id="searchComponent-2"> or when I make more like 3 or 4 or 5 search COmponet data.Could you teach me how to write code at Larvel Cotroller pleaes?  Here is my current code.   $post_data = $request::all(); return view('pn.conf',compact('post_data')); I can revice "name" but when multipule componet like 2 , 3 ,4 I couldn't make POST revice. and Actually this is my first time to recive JS id values.

Answer (score 0):

The ID attribute is same for both the input fields in your code. (From JSFiddle). Each element must have a unique ID.

If you want to search using the two input values and want to use the existing function try this:

```js
$('#search1 #search2').keyup(function(){
$('#result').html('');
$('#state').val('');

var searchField1 = $('#search-1').val();
var searchField2=$('#search-2').val();

var expression1 = new RegExp(searchField1, "i");
var expression2 = new RegExp(searchField2, "i");
$.getJSON('js/data.json', function(data) {
$.each(data, function(key, value){
if (value.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.location.search(expression) != -1 || value.name.search(expression2) != -1 || value.location.search(expression2) != -1)
{

$('#result').append(
'<li class="list-group-item link-class"' +
' data-name="' + value.name + '"' + 
' data-code="' + value.code + '"' + 
' data-location="' + value.location + '"' + 
' data-image="' + value.image + '"' + 
'>'+value.name+'</li>');
}
});
});
```

Comment: although that is an error in this sample, that does not solve the problem :)

Comment: Dear @P.B.UDAY Thank you for comment. Yes I know in this sample it doesn't work I couldn't work in here. but it worked my project. Do me a favor Could you show me code how to adjust  please? I tried lot but I have no idea how to adjust ID attribute and unique ID

Comment: Dear @P.B.UDAY Thank you very much for code. I really apreciate your help. Sorry I use another person's code but I never forget your help Thank you so much.